# Play YouTube videos in the background audio only

Tags: android

Is it possible to play YouTube videos in the background with screen off?

How can I approach to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about programming.  You may be able to get help at http://android.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: [Vanced](https://vancedapp.com/) is a clone / rip of YouTube Premium (formerly Red) that plays in background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could download the video audio only by using http://keepvid.com or download an app from Google Play, such as AudioPocket.

The Youtube Red which you pay for it and doesn't have that restriction